# ffmpeg working fine directly on server but not from PHP webpage

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, exec

I have manually installed ffmpeg and required packages on CentOS 5.1(Final).

If I fire the command directly on server using putty, it converts video in required format but not able to run same command from PHP webpage using exec() function.

I checked exec() command permission and it is fine.

ffmpeg installation directory : /root/ffmpeg_build/
ffmpeg file path : /root/bin/

Please guide me what could be the problem.

Comment: can you share your php exec command.

Comment: I sorted out by myself, actually it was parent directory permission issue. Thanks for your efforts.